# using crontab to restart php-fpm will randomly only stop fpm

Tags: php, cron

I use this configuration to restart `php-fpm` every 15 minutes, but after this script runs for 4-5 times, I've found that it sometimes only stops fpm, and does not start it again. This seems to occur randomly.

```
*/15 * * * * /etc/init.d/php-fpm stop && /etc/init.d/php-fpm start
```

or

```
*/15 * * * * /etc/init.d/php-fpm stop ; /etc/init.d/php-fpm start
```

So, is there a different way to restart `fpm` when calling it in a CRON job? What would be the correct way to call this restart?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running two commands run single `restart`

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
```